# Column ambiguously defined error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT itemname,
       price,
       itemfamily,
       f.familyname
FROM item_master i
JOIN item_family f ON f.familyid=i.itemfamily
JOIN
  (SELECT min(price) AS min1,
          itemfamily
   FROM item_master
   GROUP BY itemfamily) t ON t.itemfamily=i.itemfamily
WHERE price= min1;
```

Am getting:

> COLUMN AMBIGUOUSLY DEFINED ERROR

while executing this query

Comment: I think you should add more details about your table layout and simply try to reduce it to a minimal example...

Comment: Always alias everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itemfamily` is a valid column in both `item_master` and `item_family`.  You must specify which one you're referring to by its alias in your select statement.

Either:

```
SELECT
    itemname,
    price,
    i.itemfamily,
    f.familyname
```

or:

```
SELECT
    itemname,
    price,
    f.itemfamily,
    f.familyname
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because both tables (`item_master & item_family`  )contain `itemfamily` column.So specifying just  `itemfamily` in select query will not work.You explicitly need to specify from which table you need `itemfamily` column. 
So either use `i.itemfamily` or `t.itemfamily` in select clause.

```
SELECT itemname,
       price,
       i.itemfamily,
       f.familyname
```

or

```
SELECT itemname,
       price,
       t.itemfamily,
       f.familyname
```